# getText crowdfounded translation

Tags: php, internationalization, gettext, crowdsourcing

I'm looking for a script (there has to be one) that help me to let me user translate my getText based [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) project.

Right now, I don't have time to create a solution on my one, so I were looking for some proper open-source solution using Google Search, but I could not find anything.

There are a lot of commercial solutions for this, but I would like to use a simple PHP alternative on my own server. It does not have to have a lot of features; I just want to select the languages I need and let the people translate and check translations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any solutions in PHP, but there are several open source projects for web-based translation tools. For example:

- [Weblate](http://weblate.org/) is based on Python/Django and supports [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) integration. I think it is used by [phpMyAdmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin), so it should be suitable for PHP projects.
- [Zanata](http://zanata.org/) is written in Java and used by [JBoss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JBoss).

I also found [SimplePO on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/simplepo/) which is written in PHP, but it does not seem to support plural forms. There is also [a more recently updated fork on GitHub](https://github.com/pacifists/simplepo).